# Neng [能] vs Ke yi [可以]

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

What is the main differences between 能，and 可以? They both mean "to be able to", or simply "can", correct?

Comment: consult grammars on modal (auxiliary) verbs, search web using "Chinese auxiliary verbs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a substantial difference between the following contrast pair:
a. 我能说汉语。
b. 我可以说汉语。
In a., neng 能 indicates that I have the ability to speak Chinese while in b. keyi 可以 implies that this action, my speaking Chinese can be carried out if asked or allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Neng primarily means that the current CIRCUMSTANCES ALLOW you to carry out a certain action. Ke Yi has the sense of being ALLOWED (or asked) to do something. If you want to say, I have the ability to do something, as in an acquired ability such as speaking Chinese, you should definitely use this word.: 会 hui4.